# How to determine if a v8::Object is a v8::TypedArray and which one it is

Tags: v8

I'm trying to extract type information and data in a C++ function from a typed array passed in from JavaScript.

What I noticed is that `v8::Value::IsObject` returns true, `v8::Value::IsArray` returns false and `v8::TypedArray::Cast` always returns a `v8::TypedArray` object regardless if it's a typed array or not.

I can see and access the elements with `v8::Object::Get`, but I'm not treating it as an array as IsArray returned false.

How do I properly detect a typed array in v8? How do I find out what the type of the elements are (signed/unsigned/float? 8/16/32/64?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try v8::Value::IsTypedArray() ?

Comment: Apparently I have been looking at out-of-date documentation. This and the other IsXyArray functions are what I was looking for.

Comment: Ok, good. Things change fast in the APIs so its crucial to stay on top of things. For this and other reasons I actually wrote a wrapper for v8 and SM: https://github.com/markusmoenig/jsenginewrapper